# Regex error showing an empty list although the pattern is there in lyrics string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

```
import re
lyrics = '''Twelve drummers drumming, eleven pipers piping
Ten lords a leaping, nine ladies dancing, eight maids a milking
Seven swans a swimming, six geese a laying, five gold rings
Four calling birds, three French hens
Two turtle doves and a partridge in a pear tree
'''
xmasReExp = re.compile(r'\d+\s\w+')
print(xmasReExp.findall(lyrics))
```

Comment: Is `\d+` supposed to match the number words `twelve`, `five` ,etc? That only matches numerical strings like `12`, `5`, etc.

Comment: Would you mind using code blocks, to make it easier to read your code?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: _although the pattern is there in lyrics string_ Evidently not, right? What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the numbers that are written with words in the text `lyrics`. As RegEx is not able to understand a word, you need to solve that first. To do that you could:

- Create a mapping from word to digit
- Apply the mapping on the text
- Use regex on the new text, to get the numbers

#### Sample

```
import re

# mapping
word_digit_map = {
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3,
    "four": 4,
    "five": 5,
    "six": 6,
    "seven": 7,
    "eight": 8,
    "nine": 9,
    "ten": 10,
    "eleven": 11,
    "twelve": 12,
}

lyrics = '''Twelve drummers drumming, eleven pipers piping
Ten lords a leaping, nine ladies dancing, eight maids a milking
Seven swans a swimming, six geese a laying, five gold rings
Four calling birds, three French hens
Two turtle doves and a partridge in a pear tree
'''

# apply mapping
for word in word_digit_map.keys():
    lyrics = lyrics.lower().replace(word, str(word_digit_map[word]))

# Use regex
xmasReExp = re.compile(r'\d+')
print(xmasReExp.findall(lyrics))
```

#### Out

```
['12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
```

Answer (score -2):

The result is correct, i.e. an empty list. `\d` means digits and you don't have a matching pattern in `lyrics`.

Comment: Your answer, while technically correct, is not helpful.